# Yarn is using an incompatible version of node, inspite of being installed w nvm

Tags: yarnpkg, nvm

So, yarn is installd on the bin for v16.4.2 and yet...

```
jmccarrell-MBP:g2r-android jmccarrell$ nvm version
v16.14.2
jmccarrell-MBP:g2r-android jmccarrell$ which yarn
/Users/jmccarrell/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/yarn
jmccarrell-MBP:g2r-android jmccarrell$ yarn
yarn install v1.22.10
[1/5]   Validating package.json...
error gotoroom-monorepo@0.0.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=16". Got "14.17.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

It appears illogical, so what am i missing?

How can I futher troubleshoot this?

I'm stuck.

Comment: Check if you are using multiple node version managers. in my case, in I installed volta at some point and forgot which was messing up with nvm.

Comment: that was exactly what happened to me! haha.

Comment: Thanks Ravi. one of my fav SC2 casters is also named Ravi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the commenter Ravi was correct.

i needed to uninstall volta.
dont have both nvm and volta installed; especially if you intend to forget about one of those tools and it gets out of date.